# Unable to delete record from sqlite db using Navicat

Tags: database, sqlite, navicat

I'm unable to delete record from sqlite db using Navicat. The error reads: `Error constraint failed'

I get the same thing if I try to delete with the console using an sql command:

```
sqlite> delete from myTable where sort = '965';
constraint failed
sqlite>
```

any idea why this might be happening.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this table has a Field which is referenced as a FK in another table, so the SQlite saying

```
"I can,'t delete it, its inuse in another table"
```

Comment: yes, you're right. there's a myTable_id in another catalogue_myTable table. would I have to delete that reference first? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.schema` command of the `sqlite3` shell to show all table definitions.
Then you can see which constraint on `myTable` or a child table blocks you from deleting.

If there is a foreign key constraint in another table, you have to delete all records in that table that reference your `965` record before you can delete the record itself.